# Call a function from a separate Javascript file from HTML isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js

I have an html file **index.html** that calls a javascript function from the file **app.js** when a user types in a textbox. Basically, the purpose is to check if the user input is a correct option by comparing to the data in a json file. The user input is a computer username that has an ip address so if the input matches a username and returns an ip address, then the text box will be highlighted in green so the user knows its correct. If it's not a valid username, then it will highlight in red.

**Index.html**

```
    <script src='/Users/.../Project/app.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="User name" oninput="checkName(this.value);" required>
```

**App.js**

```
function checkName(name){
   var contents = fs.readFileSync("jData.json");
   var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
   var x = jsonContent[name].ip_1gb;
   console.log(x);
   if ( x == '') {
      document.getElementById("username").style.boxShadow = "0 0 3px red";
   } else {
      document.getElementById("username").style.boxShadow = "0 0 3px green";
}
```

The problem is that the checkName function isn't being called when I input text in the text box. I specify the entire path of app.js so I don't know why it's not being called. The app.js file is one directory higher than the html file since I put the html file in a "views" folder.

Path of app.js: /Users/.../Project/app.js

Path of html file: /Users/.../Project/views/index.html

If someone could help, that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you see an error message in the JavaScript console in the browser?

Comment: Also, there's a syntax error in your checkName() function. There's no closing bracket on the else statement

Comment: Adam is right. Use a proper editor so you don't make silly mistakes like missing braces

Comment: Which editor are you using? You have at least two syntax errors...

Comment: sorry there's no syntax errors in the actual file. must have forgotten some brackets when editing the stackoverflow post. also, there are no error messages in the console. I even put a try catch inside the function to see if there's an error but it seems like it doesn't even hit the function

Comment: I actually do get an error in the Javascript console. It says "referenceError: checkName is not defined" even though I changed the path like in the suggestion down below

Comment: When I load the page, I get this error: The resource from “http://localhost:3000/app.js” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Answer (score 1):

yout relative file paths seems to be incorrect, use path starting with "../" to one directory backward and starts there or "../../" to move to two directory backward. Details can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/).

Accourding to your location of app.js which is located two level above your html file, your code should be:

```
 <script src='../../app.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: I have tried doing what you suggested but it still seems that the function isn't being executed. If you go back two directories (../../) then wouldn't you end up in the directory that is the parent of Project since you start in the directory that contains index.html (views directory)? I also tried doing ../app.js which didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

So there are multiple things wrong with the above...
You don't specify a script by the entire `UNIX` path, just from the web root, so whatever the web root is. I assume your web root is `/Project`, so only specify that.
There is no closing bracket on the else statement your checkName() function. So as it stands, your code should look like this:

```
function checkName(name){
   var contents = fs.readFileSync("jData.json");
   var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
   var x = jsonContent[name].ip_1gb;
   console.log(x);
   if ( x == '') {
      document.getElementById("username").style.boxShadow = "0 0 3px red";
   } else {
      document.getElementById("username").style.boxShadow = "0 0 3px green";
    }
}
```

But, as better practice, you should add an event listener to the input, and call it that way, instead of oninput. So like this (in your App.js file):

```
var usernameField = document.querySelector("input[name=username]");

usernameField.addEventListener("input", function() {
   var contents = fs.readFileSync("jData.json");
   var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
   var x = jsonContent[name].ip_1gb;
   console.log(x);
   if ( x == '') {
      document.getElementById("username").style.boxShadow = "0 0 3px red";
   } else {
      document.getElementById("username").style.boxShadow = "0 0 3px green";
    }
})
```